# Why doesn't Scala infer the right type of ValidationNel?

Tags: scala, type-inference, scalaz

```
    def isEven(x: Int) = 
          if (x % 2 == 0) x.successNel else "not even".failureNel
```

In the above code, the return type of `isEven` is inferred as `scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[_ <: String],Int]`

Whereas explicitly specifying the return type works,

```
    def isEven(x: Int): ValidationNel[String, Int] = 
          if (x % 2 == 0) x.successNel else "not even".failureNel
```

Can someone explain what's going on behind the scenes here? Is this a limitation of Scala's type inference system?

I'm trying to use the above function in the following expression,

```
(isEven(4) |@| isEven(6) |@| isEven(8) |@| isEven(10)) {_ + _ + _ + _}
```

and only the second variant (with explicit return type) works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`scalaz.NonEmptyList[String]` is a sub type of `scalaz.NonEmptyList[_ <: String]`, meaning `scalaz.ValidationNEL[String,Int]` is a sub type of `scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[_ <: String],Int]`. The compiler just give you a more precise type in this case...

**Edit:** the *raisin bread* operator requires an `Applicative` instance. In this case I suppose that scalaz provide such instance for `ValidationNel[String, ?]`, but not for the more precise type inferred for your `isEven`.

A simpler manifestation of that can be observed with `Option`:

```
val some = Some(1)
val none = None
(some |@| none)(_ + _) // Cannot find implicit Applicative[Some] :(
```

You can view that as an intersect limitation of local type inference. You could also say that FP doesn't always play well with OO. I would suggest following good practices and annotate all your public method and implicits with explicit types.

Comment: Okay makes sense. I've edited my question to add an expression. Can you answer why it doesn't compile when using the first variant of isEven?

Comment: Okay if I get it right, an Implicit defined for M[T] will not work for M[+T] or M[A <: T]?

Comment: If you ask for an `implicit Applicative[T]` (`Applicative` is invariant), the compiler looks for an `Applicative[T]`, as you would expect.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to explain more details about :

**why `scalaz.Validation[scalaz.NonEmptyList[_ <: String],Int]` this can not work with `|@|`?**

`isEven(4) |@| isEven(6) ...`

First of all `isEven(4)` is trying to `implicitly` convert it from `Validation[+E, +A]` type to `ApplyOps[F0.M,F0.A]`type with `|@|` operator. as the `implicit` method in [ApplySyntax](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/5d453fe3e2548f829d26a3b033b82b36c06731fd/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/syntax/ApplySyntax.scala#L49):

```
  implicit def ToApplyOpsUnapply[FA](v: FA)(implicit F0: Unapply[Apply, FA]) =
    new ApplyOps[F0.M,F0.A](F0(v))(F0.TC)
```

As the above code, for this `implicit` conversion, we also need an **implicitly** `F0: Unapply[Apply, FA]` variable. for `UnApply` `implicits`, it's in the [UnApply](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/fabab8f699d56279d6f2cc28d02cc2b768e314d7/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Unapply.scala#L214):

```
  implicit def unapplyMFA[TC[_[_]], M0[_[_], _], F0[_], A0](implicit TC0: TC[M0[F0, ?]]): Unapply[TC, M0[F0, A0]] {
    type M[X] = M0[F0, X]
    type A = A0
  } =
    new Unapply[TC, M0[F0, A0]] {
      type M[X] = M0[F0, X]
      type A = A0
      def TC = TC0
      def leibniz = refl
    }
```

As the `Validation` type, it's using the `unapplyMFA` `implicits` variable. In there we also found it's looking for another **implicits** `TC0: TC[M0[F0, ?]]` variable. as the before `ToApplyOpsUnapply`, In there `TC0` will be `Apply` type, that's also can be `Applicative` type. so it will try to look for the `Validation` to `Applicative` **implicits**, it's in the [Validation.scala](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz/blob/c0e4b531847348e1fd533c7d3605fe69320dde91/core/src/main/scala/scalaz/Validation.scala#L535)

```
  implicit def ValidationApplicative[L: Semigroup]: Applicative[Validation[L, ?]] =
    new Applicative[Validation[L, ?]] {
      override def map[A, B](fa: Validation[L, A])(f: A => B) =
        fa map f

      def point[A](a: => A) =
        Success(a)

      def ap[A, B](fa: => Validation[L, A])(f: => Validation[L, A => B]) =
        fa ap f
    }
```

for the `Semigroup` definition:

```
trait Semigroup[F]  { self => //F is invariant, unlike Option[+A]
```

So the problem is:  `F` is **type invariant**, not like the `Option[+A]`, compiler could not find an appropriate **Applicative** implicits for this type `Validaiton`.

There is a small demo for how to enable type variant for this:

```
  def isEven(x: Int): Validation[NonEmptyList[_ <: String], Int] =
    if (x % 2 == 0) x.successNel else "not even".failureNel


  val res: String = foo(isEven(4))

  def foo[FA](v: FA)(implicit F0: Unapply[Apply, FA]): String = "foo bar"

  implicit def ValidationApplicative[L]: Applicative[Validation[L, ?]] =
    new Applicative[Validation[L, ?]] {
      override def map[A, B](fa: Validation[L, A])(f: A => B) =
        fa map f

      def point[A](a: => A) =
        Success(a)

      def ap[A, B](fa: => Validation[L, A])(f: => Validation[L, A => B]) =
      //fa ap f
        null
    }
```

In there we just **unbind** `L` from `Semigroup`, so now this is type variant. just for fun;).